# Understanding node.js server directory structure and security

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, security

Sorry if this is a straightforward question, but I was not able to find answer to it online. I have not worked with node.js previously, but am trying to set up a project to play around with. I usually use git to commit any changes to projects repository that is afterwards deployed to the server.

With node am I safe to have a public repo containing files like server.js, config folder, package.json file etc.. basically things that demonstrate how server works.

If I did miss something out please feel free to add info

Comment: Yes, however, note that if there are any vulnerabilities in said code, having it publicly available will make them easier to find. (both by people who would notify you and those who wouldn't.) Though, i'd consider this to not be a very big problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the only thing you do not want to push to github are secrets associated with any APIs you may be associated with.  Those should be added as environment variables where the server is hosted.